# how to display all components in home page

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router-dom

am stuck with a problem , I want to display my all components in home page like service, about and contact page, here is only visible home and footer

This is the App.js file where i located all routs for negotiation my components

> App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Service from './Components/Services';
import About from './Components/About';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import Footer2 from './Components/Footer2';
import Contact from './Components/Contact';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <Navbar/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/services">
            <Service />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/contact">
            <Contact />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      <Footer2 />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my navbar.js file where i made my navbar using bootstrap

> navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div >
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
                    <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/home" ><img src="https://www.abc27.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/55/2020/04/doodle.png?w=640" alt="coco-cola" className="coco" /></NavLink>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
                        <i class="far fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item active">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/home" style={{ color: 'white' }}>HOME <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName='menu-active' to="/services" style={{ color: 'white' }}>SERVICES</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName='menu-active' to="/about" style={{ color: 'white' }}>ABOUT</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName='menu-active' to="/contact" style={{ color: 'white' }}>CONTACT</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this?

Comment: Can't you simply render the other components inside `<Home>`?

Answer (score 0):

put all the pages inside the home route tag and use ids to scroll to a specific component. if you want to show all the pages inside the home page you don't need to create their routes

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
    <Navbar/>`enter code here`
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <Home />
          <Service />
          <About />
          <Contact />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    <Footer2 />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```